# LaTeX Beamer: Using \againframe with squeeze option

Tags: latex, beamer

When I write:

```
\begin{frame}[label=foo,squeeze]
...
\end{frame}
```

and later use `\againframe{foo}` to repeat the frame, the content on the repeated frame is not "squeezed" (and in my case too long to fit on the slide).

How do I combine `\againframe` with the `squeeze` option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can do:

```
\againframe[squeeze]{foo}
```